# laravel session key for groupby

Tags: php, laravel

> Hi I need the $clave of the session for i can delete it session.how i can do it? Thanks

```
$carrito=Session::get('cart');

$grouped = Session::get('cart')->groupBy('vendedor');

foreach($carrito as $clave => $carro) {
    echo $clave ; //I need to put these keys in the <a> to be able to delete the session of that item because when applying groupby it does not give me the session key. 
}

@foreach($grouped as $id => $value)
    @foreach($value as $key => $cartItem)
        <a href="#" onclick="removeFromCartView(event, {{ $clave}})" class="text-right pl-4"><i class="la la-trash"></i></a>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Could you plz dump & paste the result of $grouped variable ?

Comment: Thanks i resolved it with  ->groupBy('vendedor', $preserveKeys = true)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with `->groupBy('vendedor', $preserveKeys = true)`

*Answered by @Carlos in the comments*